# How to set next layer's boundary to be limited to previous layer's outline?

Tags: color, gimp, layers, illustration

You draw the black ink outline of an object as an enclosed ellipsoid shape, and therefore want the next layer, which you'll use to color-in the ellipsoid, to be bounded to that previous ink layer, to avoid excess coloring outside of that bounded ink outline. How (in Gimp)?

Edit: Not asking for a perfect vector-friendly oval. But instead any free-form shape like how any comic book inker has to deal with:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Create a Layer group
- Draw the ellipsoid in white (not black) as a layer in the group
- Add a color layer above the ellipsoid in the same group
- Set the color layer to "Multiply"

[image]

---

If you have to paint the shape anyway (rendering a path, for instance), but want to test colors, then a simpler solution:

- Add a layer mask to you color layer, initialized to black
- Bucket-fill the selection to white
- You can then fill the layer proper with anything (color, pattern, gradient...) **without any selection** and the visible area will be controlled by the layer mask.

[image]

Comment: How about doing this for a free-form shape that is simply a contour outline (no fill), possibly with even some intermittent open-ended gaps along the line? Sorry ,didn't  mean ellipsoid as an oval. And might need to embellish remaining steps pertaining to the new layer. Poor knowledge of masks and layer groups.

Comment: Gimp doesn't know "contours". it's a bitmap editor, so you have to fill your shape. You can also use Path instead of contours, but you have to render the path  at some point (Select from path, Bucket-fill). If you do this things are simpler; you add a layer mask to your layer, fill it with black, then get a selection from the path and fill with white.

Comment: Yeah, filling it with black and making a layer group of that makes sense. Hope the steps in the answer could be expanded with what's next? Where is the new layer. What to do with the new layer with that layer group. Does the layer group implement gimp's "Layer Boundary"?

Comment: See augmented answer

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked to do this in GIMP, so I apologize in advance for suggesting something different. What you are describing sounds like something that would be much easier done using a vector image editor, such as Inkscape which is also free and open source like GIMP.

Basically, in vector software you can draw an ellipse, which is made from a vector path. You can then add a stroke, or a fill. You can change these at any time. This also dispenses with the need to put the elements on separate layers.

Once you have created something in Inkscape, you can copy and paste it into GIMP.

An example of an ellipse in Inkscape, with a fill and stroke being applied and changed.

[image]

You can also convert a shape to Bézier paths, which work a bit like GIMP's Paths Tool, and you can then edit these as one object. For example:

[image]

Comment: Please see new edit to question, per comment previously made concerning complexity of the ink outline. Besides that, Bezier paths would be difficult to fit on ink drawings made by hand, for example inking a character like Wolverine

Comment: @user61020 - actually Inkscape is perfect for shapes like the one you added - not difficult at all to [reproduce with the Bézier tool](https://imgur.com/N7maJm3).  Drawing characters like Wolverine is a completely different thing though.

Comment: More painterly effects are better suited to raster software, although might even be worthwhile looking at something like Krita which is also free and open source. It has vector layers which can be filled and stroked like Inkscape, and also can be used for digital painting - a bit like half way between GIMP and Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

Different answer:

If your outline has a significant thickness (at least 2px) and is closed:

- Activate the outline layer
- Fuzzy select the inside of the outline
- `Select > Grow` by one or two pixels
- Add a layer below the outline
- Bucket-fill the selection in the new layer

The possible "bleed" caused by the selection growth is masked by the outline. A similar effect can be achieved by bucket-filling the selection after putting the pain tool in `Behind` mode.

If you paint on the same layer, in Gimp 2.10 the bucket-fill tool has a line-art mode:

[image]

As above, it is better to paint "under" the line art.